# Prevent chrome from sending device info to servers in Requests

Tags: google-chrome, webserver, metadata, data-transfer

This is what a simple chrome request looks like.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: keep-alive
DNT: 1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8
```

How can prevent chrome from sending the User-Agent to the server?

Comment: You can't prevent that. You may use something to change/spoof the user-agent but something must be sent.

Comment: @ChanganAuto then how can i change it?

Comment: Search for extensions at the store.